# Calling batch file reports: "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: batch-file

I have one batch file that suppose to call another. I read that `call` command is used in this case. Although error message appears:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

The path is not wrong 100% sure. This is the caller run.bat

```
@echo off
call xslt\projects\asp-bus\implementation\batch\ant-start.bat
pause
```

and this is the called `ant-start.bat`

```
set ant="../../../../infrastucture/apache-ant-1.10.0/bin/ant.bat"
call %ant%
pause
```

Comment: In your `ant-start.bat` script you'll have to replace forward slashes `/` with backslashes `\\`. Windows doesn't work with forward slashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each batch file, the paths are relative to the working folder you are running the batch file from, not the folder that contains the batch file itself.  You either need to use absolute paths (e.g. starting with `C:\`), or to make sure that when each batch file is run from a working folder where the relative paths make sense.

If you're launching `run.bat` from a Windows shortcut, you can set the "Start In" folder from the shortcut's Properties dialog.  When `ant-start.bat` is called, it will run from the same folder as `run.bat`.

To fix the problem, you might need to change `ant-start.bat` to

```
set ant="infrastucture/apache-ant-1.10.0/bin/ant.bat"
call %ant%
pause
```

Alternatively, you could put a `cd` command in one of the batch files, to force it to use an appropriate working folder.

Bear in mind that if you set the `%ant%` variable to a relative path as above, using the variable will only work from a folder where that relative path makes sense.